# Spacemacs: "No such file or directory, Racket.exe"

Tags: path, racket, spacemacs

I'm running Windows 10, and I'm trying to get Racket working on spacemacs. I've added it to my `.spacemacs` file, so `racket-mode` starts just fine, but whenever I try to evaluate an expression using `SPC m s e` I get `Searching for program: No such file or directory, Racket.exe`.

I've added Racket.exe to my PATH variable, but it doesn't seem to do anything. I've seen something about geiser, but according to [this](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/tree/master/layers/%2Blang/racket) I don't need that to make Racket work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I met the same problem at Emacs, and then I changed the configuration code into

```
(require 'racket-mode)
(setq racket-racket-program "C:/Program Files/Racket/racket.exe")
(setq racket-raco-program "C:/Program Files/Racket/raco.exe")
```

Change the program path to an absolute path.
Then the error disappears.

I hope useful to you.

Comment: This worked for me. To be more specific, you need to add this into the `user-config` function in your `.spacemacs` file - it's right at the end.